# How to fetch data from different tables and send it in json format

Tags: json, yii

I am creating functionalities in Yii + extjs-4. I am having two tables as-
Poll                                 Option
-pollId                            -optionId
-pollQuestion                      -option
-Isactive                          -pollId
-IsPublished

i am creating sendData function,in which i have to retrieve record for given pollId and also options for this pollId from option table and want to send this all record values in json encoede format. So how to send this different tables data together in json format?
Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relation at your Poll model (I realized that Poll has many Options). So define:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'options'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Option', 'poll_id'),
    );
}
```

Where `poll_id` is Option table field.

Than you need to get array with all data (formatted as you need) like this:

```
$data = $pollModel->getAttributes();
foreach ($pollModel->options as $option) {
    $data = array_merge($data, $option->getAttributes());
}
CJSON::encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanx for reply sir....I have implemented as you have told. But its giving error as- 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

Comment: and $pollModel is an object `Poll`? Which has `relations` method as mentioned above? And you have model `Option` with `poll_id` field?

Comment: i have modified method as per my objects name as-                             $data= $poll->getAttributes();    I am having relation as-'polloptions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Polloption', 'pollId'). i had made chnages accordingly.

Comment: sir.....suppose i have $record1=poll::model()->findByPk($model->pollId); and  $record2=Polloption::model()->findByAttributes(array('pollId'=>$record1->pollId));                   record1 is having question from poll table and record2 is having options of this question which are retrieved from polloption table. So i want to send this question and its options into json format.So how to json_encode both these records?

Comment: Have you understood that `$poll` is Poll model? So you need to use:
`$record1=poll::model()->findByPk($model->pollId);`
`$data = $record1->getAttributes();`
`foreach ($record1->polloptions as $option) {`
`    $data = array_merge($data, $option->getAttributes());`
`}`
`CJSON::encode($data);`

Comment: Thanx sir its working....It is displaying all fields of Poll table.If i want to display only question,what changes i need to do. Now the other problem is.My option table is having multiple options with same questionId. By using above method,It is giving me only last option inserted for this questionId. If i want to display all options for same QuestionId. So how to implement this...please help me....

Comment: It should be working... Try to debug `$pollModel->options` it must be an array of all options. If not - check relations and your DB data

Comment: In poll model,i am having relation as 'polloptions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Polloption', 'pollId'),